# Swift Breadth-first search

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'm going slightly crazy with a BFS for a binary tree.

It returns the correct elements, but it appears that I insert the same Node into the queue multiple times.

What is going wrong? The algorithm shouldn't be this difficult but I seem to be making it..

```
func breadthFirstSearch(_ data: Int) -> Node? {
    var queue = [Node]()
    if (self.data == data) { return self }
    queue.append(self)
    var tempNode = queue[0]

    while queue.count > 0 {
        if (tempNode.data == data) { return tempNode }

        if let lft = tempNode.left {
            queue.append(lft)
        }
        if let rht = tempNode.right {
            queue.append(rht)
        }
        tempNode = queue[0]
        queue.remove(at: 0)

    }
    return nil
}
```

Where tree is

```
class Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    var data : Int
    var left: Node?
    var right: Node?

    init(_ data : Int) {
        self.data = data
    }
    var description: String {
        return String(data) + ((left != nil) ? left!.description : "") + ((right != nil) ? right!.description : "")
    }

    func insert(_ data: Int) {
        if (self.data > data) {
            if let lft = self.left {
                lft.insert(data)
            } else {
                let left = Node(data)
                self.left = left
            }
        }
        else {
            if let rgt = self.right {
                rgt.insert(data)
            } else {
                let right = Node(data)
                self.right = right
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

and inserting

```
var binaryTree = Node(10)
binaryTree.insert(5)
binaryTree.insert(20)
binaryTree.insert(3)
binaryTree.insert(15)
binaryTree.breadthFirstSearch(4)
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? In the example in your question the number `4` is never inserted in the tree so any search for it would return `nil`. Please provide an example that showcases the problem, what output/result you are expecting to get in that case, and what output/result you're actually getting.

Comment: Your `tempNode` is unnecessary and it is making your algorithm to fail.

Comment: move the last 2 lines in the while loop to the top of the while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to remove your `tempNode` variable and just always use the head of the queue:

```
func breadthFirstSearch(_ data: Int) -> Node? {
    var queue = [self]

    while let head = queue.first {
        queue.remove(at: 0)

        if (head.data == data) {
          return head
        }

        if let lft = head.left {
            queue.append(lft)
        }

        if let rht = head.right {
            queue.append(rht)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Your original implementation would actually iterate over the first (root) node twice. I have also removed the unnecessary double checking in the beginning.

Now you can also see the difference against Depth First Search:

```
func depthFirstSearch(_ data: Int) -> Node? {
    var stack = [self]

    while let head = stack.popLast() {
        if (head.data == data) {
            return head
        }

        if let lft = head.left {
            stack.append(lft)
        }

        if let rht = head.right {
            stack.append(rht)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```